# Geometry Nodes: How can i prevent an instanced mesh to protrude over the "border" of the parent face?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I distributed points on a face with material_1 (green). I instanced a disk on the points.
**How can i prevent the disks to protrude over the edgeloop that surrounds material_1?**
(Deleting the disks in whole, cut off a part (not with knife project, solution should be in geometry nodes) or moving them "away from the border" would all be fine solutions)

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am honest: i would provide a solution if you would provide a blend file so that i don't have to rebuild it manually. And i am sure some others would attract that too

Comment: I would provide a file if i could upload one, but how^^? I can only add images

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: added the blendfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way:

[image]

Separate using material selection and test the proximity of each disk point to this selection.

If the distance is less than 0.1 (given as Z shift for the instances) + epsilon (0.001 which is important), then consider this is to keep.

In order to delete all the realized instance, accumulate the proximity test above grouped by island index (instance index) and test if the total differs from the instance vertex count.

If this is the case: delete it.

Increasing the density, that gives the following:

[image]

Comment: "Look at mesh island x, check if each vertex has a certain proximity to material2 and when the amount of vertexes that fullfill that is not equal to the amount of vertexes of a disk delete it". Thats a really elegant solution man.